# Can't hide out of stock products' price in live search suggestions - Woocommerce Emallshop

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I have an issue I can't solve on a wordpress woocommerce website.
We chose to display the out of stock products so that our clients can see all the products and don't imagine we don't propose some of them when they're out of stock. Anyway.
I found a php snippet to hide the price of these out of stock products on categories and product pages. But I can't, for the life of me, hide the price in the suggestions that appear when one uses the live search bar in the header (ajax search).
The theme is Emallshop by PressLayout.

I've used this snippet and tried to put it in several files : functions.php, theme-function.php and woo-functions.php.

```
    /**
 * @snippet       Hide Price If Out of Stock @ WooCommerce Frontend
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 6
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_hide_price_if_out_stock_frontend', 9999, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_hide_price_if_out_stock_frontend( $price, $product ) {
   if ( is_admin() ) return $price; // BAIL IF BACKEND
   if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
      $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', '', $product );
   }
   return $price;
}
```

It works fine to hide prices of out of stock products in categories and product pages BUT NOT in the suggestions of the live search bar.

Can you help me please ? I'm no coder but I can answer questions if you ask me some about this problem ;) (and got ftp access so I can read anyfile)

My latest hint is this big chunk of code that seems to say how to get price in the suggestions... if only I knew how to transform it so that it gets price only when in stock ! Any idea ??

```
/*  Prodcut live search
 *
 * @ since EmallShop 2.0
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
if( ! function_exists( 'emallshop_products_live_search' ) ) :
    function emallshop_products_live_search() {
        
        $products = array();
        $sku_products = array();    
        
        $products = emallshop_ajax_search_products();
        $sku_products =emallshop_get_option('enable-search-by-sku', 0)
          ? emallshop_ajax_search_products_by_sku()
          : array();            

        $results = array_merge( $products, $sku_products );

        $suggestions = array();

        foreach ( $results as $key => $post ) { 
            $product        = wc_get_product( $post );
            $product_image  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->get_id() ) );

            $suggestions[] = array(
                        'id'    => esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                        'value' => esc_attr( $product->get_title() ),
                        'url'   => esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
                        'img'   => esc_url( $product_image[0] ),
                        'price' => wp_kses_post( $product->get_price_html() ),
                    );
            
        }
```

Thanks in advance !!! :D
Have a great day

Comment: Hi, can you share your website URL?

Comment: Which search plugin are you using? Some plugins use an index, so might be that it's not updated there yet.

Comment: The website is achat.crdigital.fr (but you won't see prices if not connected, it's for aproved professionals only). @Bhautik

Comment: @ChrostipSchaejn I think it's not a plugin but a functionality integrated in the theme (Emallshop). Could you explain to me a bit more the "index" part of your answer please ? D'you mean it would index all products and not update them often in the search ? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Some search plugins have a feature to index (create a search index) with all product data, so they are faster. Other search plugins use direct SQL queries which is also fast but can be performance relevant when having some traffic. Your filter looks good and it's working. To debug it and be sure that you are at the correct code part: Can you replace in your second snippet `'price' => wp_kses_post( $product->get_price_html() )` with `'price' =>'' )`?

Comment: You can also try `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_hide_price_if_out_stock_frontend', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );` and put the filter/function in your themes' functions.php.